# Как проверить текст на схожесть в питоне

Tags: python

Представим, что у меня есть определенный список (назовем его lis), в списке 10 элементов, все элементы это текст(различные фразы), по типу: Привет, добрый день, здравствуйте и тд. Так же у меня есть переменная hi, В hi записано "Прлвет", именно прЛвет. Как проверить, есть ли в списке что то похожее на значение переменной hi?

Comment: попробуйте этот модуль для нечёткого сопоставления строк https://pypi.org/project/fuzzywuzzy/

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance